# React Native language change doesn't affect immediately

Tags: react-native, i18next

I'm using `react-native-i18n` in my project. After changing language to Arabic all text data are automatically aligned to the Right side of the screen properly. But all other components like Icons are aligning only after re-opening the app.

```
export function langSet(type){
    if(type == "en"){
    I18n.locale = type;
    const currentLocale = I18n.currentLocale();
    }else{
        I18n.locale = type;
        const currentLocale = I18n.currentLocale();
        ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
        ReactNative.I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the language occurs only if u refresh your DOM, for this you should have to make a change state that will make the DOM to refresh, 
make a dumy state

`state = {
languageChange : false
}`

then after shifting language just below that run the state change as

```
this.setState({ languageChange: !this.state.languageChange ) }
```

Comment: The actual problem is with refreshing the dom. u have any idea about how to do that in react native?

Comment: yes u have to Reload that Component again that'll refresh the DOM, you won't have to relaunch the app since reload will do that for you